# How do I repeat a discord command every 24hrs in c# using Discord.net v0.9.6?

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

How do I set a command to automatically repeat every 24 hrs?

```
private void RegisterMemeCommand()
    {
        commands.CreateCommand("meme")
            .Do(async (e) =>
            {
                int randomMemeIndex = rand.Next(FullmetalMemes.Length);
                string memeToPost = FullmetalMemes[randomMemeIndex];
                await e.Channel.SendFile(memeToPost);
            });
    }
```

I am trying to get this to execute on its own at noon everyday without me having to go into my discord and type meme.

Comment: Please see [Why may I not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Sorry for uploading the code as a image…  I'm new to SO but I did correct the issue.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to create a command. You can directly send your message to a channel with its id.

Sample code:

```
    const ulong serverId = 38297389272897UL; // the id of your server
    const ulong channelId = 78346982689343UL; // the id of the channel

    Server findServer(ulong id)
    {
        foreach(Server server in discord.Servers) // discord is your DiscorClient instance
        {
            if (server.Id == serverId)
                return server;
        }
        return null;
    }

    Channel findTextChannel(Server server, ulong id)
    {
        foreach(Channel channel in server.TextChannels)
        {
            if (channel.Id == channelId)
                return channel;
        }
        return null;
    }

    private Channel channel;
    private System.Threading.Timer timer;

    void load()
    {
        Server server = findServer(serverId);
        if (server != null)
        {
            channel = findTextChannel(server, channelId);
            if (channel != null)
                timer = new System.Threading.Timer(send, null, 0, 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24); // 24 hour interval
        }
    }

    void send(object state)
    {
        channel.SendMessage("your message");
    }
```

You can get the id of the server and the channel in Discord by right-clicking on the server or channel and click Copy ID. If you don't have this option, make sure you have checked Developer Mode in settings.